# Abort and exit commands of InstallShield not working on windows 2012 r2 server

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have existing product, that uses installshield 2011 to generate msi.

Currently we planned to support windows server 2012 R2, but the existing code is not working.

we have a scenario where we check that some dependencies are missing we abort or exit, but this is not working on windows 2012 R2.

Is there any other way to handle this, i have checked in some forum it says to return "ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE", but i cannot return from most of the part from customAction.

How can i abort the installation at the same point.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I do believe there was a problem with `abort` not resulting in an `ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE` being returned from an InstallScript custom action that was fixed along the way; you can verify this by reviewing the release notes from versions of InstallShield after the one you're using. If upgrading is an option, that might be the simplest, as InstallShield 2011 does not officially support Windows Server 2012R2. (And it helps my employer to keep paying me.)

If you want to fix the behavior with what you have, it sounds like you're saying the problem is you have a deeply nested function that cannot easily return `ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE` to the custom action entry point. The least intrusive change may be to use exceptions and [exception handling](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/Subsystems/installshield22langref/helplibrary/Exceptionhandling.htm). You can put `try`/`catch`/`endcatch` in your entry-point function (or functions), and use `Err.Raise` to throw an exception where you previously used `abort`. Unlike in the linked example, the `Err.Raise` and the `try`/`catch`/`endcatch` will intentionally be in different functions.

Note that if the function you change from using `abort` to using `Err.Raise` is called from other functions, the observed behavior may differ from those functions unless they similarly translate the exception into their preferred behavior.